# meteor-dochead: Script was added to head more than 1 time

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I have meteorjs app with FlowRouter and ReactJS. I need to load some external script file (it is small library, which is absent on Atmosphere).
How can I prevent adding more than 1 tag, when this DOM element was rendered more than 1 time?

```
MyPage = React.createClass({
  render() {
    DocHead.loadScript('someAdress');
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          //Content
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

I tried to use `DocHead.removeDocHeadAddedTags()` before `DocHead.loadScript('someAdress');`, but it does not able to remove `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put it in `componentWillMount()`, instead of `render()`. You may also want to check whether it's been loaded before loading it again.